# StreamTokenizer unescape characters

Tags: java

I'm using Java's `StreamTokenizer` in order to tokenize a code text input.
When escape characters appear in a string, the tokenizer unescapes them, while I want to keep the string the same.

For example:

```
Input: String str = "STRIN\tG";

StreamTokenizer Output: STRIN    G
Wanted Output: STRIN\tG
```

My code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.java"));
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(reader);

boolean eof = false;
do {
    int type = 0;
    type = tokenizer.nextToken();
    switch (type) {
        case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                eof = true;
                break;

            case '"':
                System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);
                break;
    }
} while (!eof);
```

**EDIT**
I choose to work with `StreamTokenizer` because the good handling of comments removing

Comment: don't use a tokenizer for this, use the split method of the String class.

Comment: to comment on your edit (and question): so, you want the output to be exactly the same as your input? why checking for tokens in the first place? what tokens do you consider? how do you plan to set them?

Comment: thats right. the output of **strings** should be exactly the same as the input.

Comment: so why are you checking for tokens? 
String output = input; will do just that, keeping the output the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873672/java-streamtokenizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`StreamTokenizer` constructor JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#StreamTokenizer%28java.io.InputStream%29) states:

> All byte values '\u0000' through '\u0020' are considered to be white space.

and `\t` is sort of \u000a... You can use the [`whitespaceChars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#whitespaceChars%28int,%20int%29) method to change this behavior.

A side note: If you choose to `println()` a string containing `\t` most/all terminals will move the cursor to the next tab position, instead of actually printing `\t`...

Cheers,

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `whitespaceChars()`? I added the row `tokenizer.whitespaceChars(\u0009, \u0009);` and it didn't help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `default` `case` and handle the character as you wish to:

```
    switch (type) {
        case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
            System.out.println("End of Line encountered.");
            break;
         case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
            System.out.print(tokenizer.sval);
            break;
        case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
            eof = true;
            break;
        case '"':
            System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print((char) type);
        }
```